# closing WCF client in async operation

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have the following code, which invokes WCF service asynchronously:

```
var client = new MyServiceClient();
Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginDo, client.EndDo, request, null).ContinueWith(t => {
    //process t.Result
});
```

What is the best way to dispose the service client instance in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Two variants to consider. Both should be placed at the beginning of the continuation block.

1.

```
try
{
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

2.

```
if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    client.Abort();
else
    client.Close();
```